Converting Markdown with Mermaid diagrams to PDF: Graphs missing in PDF output
Following this post, I'm trying to convert a Markdown document that includes Mermaid diagrams to PDF, but I'm having trouble getting the diagrams to appear in the final PDF output. The Markdown to HTML conversion works perfectly, but the PDF conversion is giving me headaches.
Here's a Minimal Working Example (MWE) of my Markdown file:
# Test Document

This is a test document with a Mermaid diagram.

```{.mermaid format=svg}
graph TD
    A[Start] --> B{Is it?}
    B -->|Yes| C[OK]
    C --> D[Rethink]
    D --> B
    B ---->|No| E[End]
```

End of document.

I'm using the following commands in cmd to convert from Markdown to HTML:
set "PATH=C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\rsvg-convert\tools"

pandoc -F "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\mermaid-filter.cmd" --lua-filter=toc-placement.lua --standalone --css=pandoc-custom-css.css --template pandoc-html-template.html input.md -o output.html

This successfully creates an HTML file with the Mermaid diagram rendered correctly (more info here and here).
However, when I try to convert this HTML to PDF, the Mermaid diagram is missing. I've tried several methods:

Using pandoc directly to PDF
Using wkhtmltopdf
Using headless Microsoft Edge
Using Microsoft Office Word
Using "Microsoft Print to PDF"

None of these methods have successfully included the Mermaid diagram in the PDF output.
Is there a reliable way to convert a Markdown document with Mermaid diagrams to PDF, ensuring that the diagrams are rendered correctly in the final output?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
P.S. For those who end-up on this page, I have now posted a better solution here.

Browsers cannot directly display mermaid diagrams that are contained in HTML pages, these must first be converted to SVG (or some other format). This conversion happens with a Javascript program that runs after the browser has loaded the HTML page, and which must finish before the conversion to PDF can start.
After converting the Markdown document to HTML using pandoc, you should obtain an output.html file like this:


<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs"></script>
<h1>Test Document</h1>
<p>This is a test document with a Mermaid diagram.</p>
<pre class="mermaid">
graph TD
    A[Start] --> B{Is it?}
    B -->|Yes| C[OK]
    C --> D[Rethink]
    D --> B
    B ---->|No| E[End]
</pre>
<p>End of document.</p>



Then run the following Node.js program (using a headless Chrome browser in puppeteer):
var browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: "new" });
var page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("output.html", {
  waitUntil: "networkidle2"
});
await page.pdf({
  path: "output.pdf"
});
await browser.close();

waitUntil: "networkidle2" waits long enough for the Markdown-to-SVG conversion to be carried out.
(Note that changes to the HTML page that happen later (after a few seconds, say) would not be reflected in the PDF. For example, if output.html looked like


var cnt = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  document.body.textContent = ++cnt
}, 1000);



the resulting PDF document would consist of an empty page.)

thanks a lot. I posted a new answer inspired by your post that uses just cmd batch, PowerShell, and headless MS Edge.

Thank Heiko Theißen for pointing me in the right direction. I've managed to solve the issue by using headless Microsoft Edge to convert the HTML (with rendered Mermaid diagrams) to PDF. Here's how I did it:

First, I converted the Markdown to HTML using pandoc with the mermaid-filter, as in my original question.

Then, I created a PowerShell script (ConvertToPDF.ps1) to use headless Edge for the PDF conversion:


$htmlPath = Resolve-Path .\doc.html
$pdfPath = Join-Path $PWD 'doc.pdf'
Write-Host "HTML file path: $htmlPath"
Write-Host "PDF file path: $pdfPath"

# Path to Edge (update if necessary)
$edgePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"

# Use Start-Process to run Edge in headless mode
$process = Start-Process -FilePath $edgePath -ArgumentList "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw", "--print-to-pdf=""$pdfPath""", """file:///$htmlPath""" -PassThru

# Wait for the process to complete (adjust timeout as needed)
$process | Wait-Process -Timeout 30 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if (Test-Path $pdfPath) {
    Write-Host "PDF file created successfully at: $pdfPath"
    exit 0
} else {
    Write-Host "Failed to create PDF file"
    exit 1
}


Finally, I updated my batch script to use this PowerShell script for the PDF conversion:

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Set environment variables
set "PATH=C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\rsvg-convert\tools"

:: Set the path to PowerShell
set "POWERSHELL_PATH=%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"

:: Convert Markdown to HTML
echo Converting Markdown to HTML...
pandoc -F "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\mermaid-filter.cmd" --lua-filter=toc-placement.lua --standalone --css=pandoc-custom-css.css --template pandoc-html-template.html sts-document-structure.md -o doc.html

:: Check if HTML file was created
if not exist doc.html (
    echo Error: HTML file was not created. Check the pandoc output above for errors.
    exit /b 1
)

:: Convert HTML to PDF using headless Microsoft Edge
echo Converting HTML to PDF using headless Microsoft Edge...
"%POWERSHELL_PATH%" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ConvertToPDF.ps1

:: Check if PDF file was created
if exist doc.pdf (
    echo Conversion complete. Output file: doc.pdf
) else (
    echo Error: PDF file was not created. Check for errors.
    exit /b 1
)

endlocal

This solution works because, as Heiko Theißen pointed out, browsers need time to render Mermaid diagrams in HTML before converting to PDF. By using headless Edge, we allow the JavaScript to run and render the diagrams before creating the PDF.
The only minor issue I'm still encountering is this warning message:
[0821/163120.931:WARNING:edge_sandbox_win.cc(116)] AdjustConfigForOrtDMLSandboxedProcess: ignore error in getting DIR_COMPONENT_USER

However, this doesn't seem to affect the PDF output, and the Mermaid diagrams are now correctly rendered in the final PDF.
This solution doesn't require installing additional software like puppeteer, making it easier to implement in environments where installing new software might be restricted.
